# Why do wettable sulphur manufacturers say never to use it within 30 days of an oil-based spray?

Tags: agriculture

And further:

1) what qualifies as an "oil-based spray" and at what amount? 
2) does this warning still apply during the rainy season-- when the need for quick cycles of medicines is necessary?

(and yes, I've tried to ask manufacturers but to no avail).

Comment: This seems to  be more of a horticultural pest control question rather than earth sciences.

Comment: @Michael Walsby I've tagged it "agriculture". Which community should I post it in instead?

Comment: I don't know much about it, so I couldn't say, but the people who run this site will know and will probably migrate your question to a more appropriate site.

Comment: @kladhest this might be a better fit over at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on SE Gardening & Landscaping